# LIBSVM - perfect confusion matrix on training set, abysmal results on test set?

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, libsvm

I am doing a project in argument mining. One of the tasks is classifying Strings as PREM(ise), CONC(lusion) or M(ajor)CONC(lusion). I am working with AAEC dataset and have a few thousand features per vector.

For the task I employ a CSVM with polynomial kernel implemented in LibSVM and accessed through WEKA.

I am performing a grid search (w/o cross-validation, its a custom code I wrote that trains an SVM on a subset of the data and prints its results) for best C, gamma. I am trying in range 10^-5 to 10^5 and 2^-15 to 2^3 respectively. I am also printing out the results on the training set and on the test set.

I either get all classified as a for both confusion matrices, or this :

```
Confusion matrix (on training set)
   a   b   c   <-- classified as
 416   0   0 |   a = PREM
   8 169   0 |   b = CONC
   5   0  80 |   c = MCONC

Confusion matrix (on test set)
   a   b   c   <-- classified as
 107   1   0 |   a = PREM
  40   0   0 |   b = CONC
  16   0   0 |   c = MCONC
```

I am not too familiar with SVMs and I am not sure whether this is supposed to be normal or anomalous. Intuitively it seems unlikely that the data is so well separable in the training set yet the result is completely off on the test set.

I am not sure how to proceed. Is this a result of not having optimal C,gamma or the data being not descriptive enough, or is this potentially a signal of a more hidden problem (e.g. filtering mistakes, overfitting)?

Advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Without seeing the data, you may either have overfitted your model to the training data and/or the train/test data have different distributions. Have you tried other algorithms like RandomForest or J48 on your data to get a base line?

Comment: @fracpete thanks for the response! How do I make sure I am not overfitting on LibSVM? I know for neural networks you make sure to stop training based on cross-val checks - but there doesn't seem to be this option for SVMs :/ As for other algorithms - not yet; I will try now and update the post.

Comment: If other algorithms exhibit similar behavior of just favoring the one class label, then the distribution in your train and test might differ enough to throw the models. Rather than using a dedicated test set, try cross-validation (and also output per train/test split information).